# Printing a JSON string and formatting it with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, node.js, json, ejs

I am trying to print and format my json code I'm getting from my DB and print it with my ejs file and CSS. right now I'm just looking at a JSON string and I don't know how to format, does anyone have any idea on what I should do? I am making an Event Planner Web App.

What I am trying to do is have a user create an account and login, then once they login they are able to view the details of the events the have created already. as you can see from the screenshot you can see the json string but I want to be able to turn that into some meaningful design and not just a random string of elements.

Current output:

[image]

```css
body {
  background-color: #FEF5DF;
}

.container1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: url("https://i.pinimg.com/564x/6f/5a/b1/6f5ab1b470beeeeaf285bb451c63ac8f.jpg");
  background-color: black;
  background-size: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

.overlay1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 2fr 1fr;
  background: rgba(77, 77, 77, .9);
  color: #FEF5DF;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

.items1 {
  padding-left: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.head1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 40px;
  transform: translateY(40px);
  transition: all 0.7s;
  hr1 {
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: solid 2px $bg;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 20px;
    transition: all .5s;
  }
}

.price1 {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(40px);
  transition: all 0.7s;
  .old {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: lighten(rgb(77, 77, 77), 40%);
  }
}

.cart1 {
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  transform: translateY(40px);
  transition: all 0.7s;
  i {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  span1 {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}

.container1:hover .overlay1 {
  opacity: 1;
  & .head {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  & hr {
    width: 75px;
    transition-delay: 0.4s;
  }
  & .price {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  & .cart {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    transition-delay: 0.6s;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="mt-4">Dashboard</h1>

<p class="lead mb-3">Welcome
  <%= user.name %>
</p>


<a href="/users/logout" class="btn btn-secondary">Logout</a>

<br>
<br>
<br>


<ul>
  <% for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) { %>
    <li>
      <%= data[i] %>

        <div class="event_age"></div>

        <div class="container1">
          <div class="overlay">
            <div class="items"></div>
            <div class="items head">
              <p> </p>
              <hr>
            </div>

            <%= data[i].comments %>
              <div class="items price">
                <p class="old"> </p>
                <p class="new"> </p>
              </div>

          </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: maybe json is not suitable for this, say, you might save yourself a lot of work if you use standard XML; though you could make it work with JavaScript. Or are you saying you want it to look like json just pretty-printed?

Comment: `<pre><%= JSON.stringify(data[i], null, 2) %></pre>`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that JSON is your problem in this case. You are using EJS, which is a JavaScript templating library. Therefore, you will have to use HTML and insert the data you want in your template like so:

```html
<ul>
  <% for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) { %>
  <li>
    <div>Location: <%= data[i].location %></div>
    <div>Name: <%= data[i].name %></div>
    <div>Event type: <%= data[i].event_type %></div>
    <div>Number of guests: <%= data[i].no_of_guests %></div>
    <div>Event age: <%= data[i].event_age %></div>
    <div>Drinks: <%= data[i].drink %></div>
    <div>Date: <%= data[i].date %></div>
    <div>Comments: <%= data[i].comments %></div>
    <div>Assets: <%= data[i].Assets %></div>
  </li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

If you want to play around with this code, I created a pen here: https://codepen.io/yvesgurcan/pen/ZEYzgyj. However, I had to put the HTML in the JavaScript file. You should be able to add this code directly to your HTML file in your project.

Make sure you read the documentation for EJS. You will find lots of information here: https://ejs.co/#docs

Hope it helps!